# How do for-lops exactly work in C++ example: calculating hashes

Tags: c++, hash, sha, execution-time, sha512

I was trying to find out how many hashes I can calculate in  which time. I am using SHA-512 (SHA-2 with 512 Bit Output). I did not code this Hashfunction, but I did a foor loop to test it. I am not really farmiliar with C++ so I do not know why the following situation occured.

When I executed the program the calculations took longer and longer. While I had about 10000 Hashes withint he first few seconds, a few hours later it took my PC about a minute to calculate 1000 Hashes... Can anybody tell me why and how to "solve" this?

This is the relevant code, I guess:

```
int fortschritt = 0;
int prozent = 0;
string temp;
stringstream convert;
string loeschen;

for (int i = 1; i <= 4294967295; i++)
{
    convert << i;
    temp = convert.str();

    loeschen = sha512(temp);

    if (((int)(i/1000)) > fortschritt)
    {
        fortschritt = (int)(i/1000);

        if (((int)(i*100)/4294967295) > prozent)
        {
            prozent = ((int)(i*100)/4294967295);
        }

        cout << fortschritt*1000 << " von 4294967295 - " << prozent << " %" << endl;
    }
}
```

The output looks like this:

```
1000 von 4294967295 - 0 %
2000 von 4294967295 - 0 %
3000 von 4294967295 - 0 %
4000 von 4294967295 - 0 %
5000 von 4294967295 - 0 %
6000 von 4294967295 - 0 %
7000 von 4294967295 - 0 %
8000 von 4294967295 - 0 %
9000 von 4294967295 - 0 %
10000 von 4294967295 - 0 %
[...]
```

I think it has something to do with the way I use the variables, but I am not sure and neither have an idea how to do it correctly.
Forgive me if this is a stupid question, but it bothered me for some time now.

Thanks in advance for any help :)

John

Comment: All those divides are not healthy for your program, make an extra counter j that goes to 1000 to enter the fortschritt if, where you reset it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like your `convert` stream grows continuously for each iteration, appending the new value each time. The easiest fix is to move the declaration of `stringstream convert;` inside the for loop to create a new one each time.

Further optimisations are certainly possible as it's not efficient to convert numbers to strings the way you are doing it for the large number of iterations in the main loop.

Comment: thanks, I will try it. Do you have a better way, how to convert the number?
The calculations work extremely faster now, thats hilariouse!

Comment: Your sha512 method takes a string and I assume you don't want to change that. I would use the string's 'fill' constructor to preallocate memory for the string once outside the loop to be large enough for the biggest number. Then just convert each integer directly into the character buffer backing the string using an efficient method such as the plain old 'C' itoa() function. The overhead of the stream can be removed entirely.